# fedora liveUSB fails, drops to debug shell

Tags: linux, fedora

Trying to install Fedora 15 via a live USB made with unetbootin. I get to the unetbootin boot menu, select Fedora-15-x86_64-Live-Desktop.is, I get to [this screen](https://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/4/42/Tours_Fedora11_006_Plymouth_Boot.png), then it drops into a debug shell with the message `sh: can't access tty: job control turned off`. The last message is dmseg is `dracut Warning: No root device "live:/dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-15-Beta-x86_64-Live-Desktop.is" found`.

Seems to be the same problem detailed [here](http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=262907). Tried to try nk1eto's solution but there is no by-label directory in /dev/disk. There's by-id, by-path and by-uuid.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exact same error, but I was using usb-creator.exe.

Solution:
Use MultiBootUSB script: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1518273

I now am typing this from within Fedora 15 x64-Live-Desktop!

Answer (score 1):

Try this [updated GUI version of MultiBootUSB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multibootusb/files/Linux/).

Answer (score 0):

When the installer starts to boot hit `Esc`. This will cause it to show messages normally hidden behind the "pretty" blue screen and will give you more information. I think you may be on the right track, though.

This http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/USBHowTo HOWTO could help you. There's a section on labelling a partition on your USB too. Use output of mount and/or dmesg to determine, which partition is your USB stick.